# how to set a pojo as a moxy?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, moxy

I have this file:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Projects")
public class Projects extends ResponseWrapper {
    private ArrayList<Project> project;
    @XmlElement(name="Project")
    public ArrayList<Project> getProject() {
        return project;
    }

    public void setProject(List<Project> list) {
        this.project = (ArrayList<Project>)list;
    }

}
```

Project has an @XMLInverseReference

```
  System.out.println(JAXBContext.newInstance(Projects.class).getClass()); //error

Exception Description: The method [setProject] or [getProject] is not defined in the object [com.tps.www.data.Projects].
```

While printing out Project.class:

```
 System.out.println(JAXBContext.newInstance(Project.class).getClass()); //OK
20:27:01,118 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8180-1) class org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext



package com.tps.www.data;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlInverseReference;
import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollection;
import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollectionOption;
import org.hibernate.annotations.NamedQueries;
import org.hibernate.annotations.NamedQuery;

import com.tps.www.util.ResponseWrapper;

@NamedQueries({ 
@NamedQuery(name = "findProjectById", query = "select p from Project p where p.projectCode = ?"),
@NamedQuery(name="findAllProject",query="from Project p")})

@Entity
@Table(name = "Project")
@XmlRootElement(name = "Project",namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
public class Project extends ResponseWrapper implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "Project_Code")
    private String projectCode;

    @Column(name = "Project_Name")
    private String projectName;
    @Column(name = "Starting_Date")
    private Date startingDate;
    @Column(name = "Expected_End_Date")
    private Date expectedEndDate;
    @Column(name = "Created_By")
    private String createdBy;

    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "project",fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Contract contract;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Service_Id")
    private Service service;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "project",fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private BudgetRequestInfo budgetRequestInfo;
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<MaterialRequestAssignment> materialRequestAssignment;

    @XmlElement(name = "Project_Code", nillable=true)
    public String getProjectCode() {
        return projectCode;
    }

    public void setProjectCode(String projectCode) {
        this.projectCode = projectCode;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "Project_Name", nillable=true)
    public String getProjectName() {
        return projectName;
    }

    public void setProjectName(String projectName) {
        this.projectName = projectName;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "Starting_Date", nillable=true)
    public Date getStartingDate() {
        return startingDate;
    }

    public void setStartingDate(Date startingDate) {
        this.startingDate = startingDate;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "Expected_End_Date", nillable=true)
    public Date getExpectedEndDate() {
        return expectedEndDate;
    }

    public void setExpectedEndDate(Date expectedEndDate) {
        this.expectedEndDate = expectedEndDate;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "Created_By", nillable=true)
    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "Contract", nillable=true)
    @XmlInverseReference(mappedBy="project")
    public Contract getContract() {
        return contract;
    }

    public void setContract(Contract contract) {
        this.contract = contract;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "Service_Id", nillable=true)
    @XmlInverseReference(mappedBy="project")
    public Service getService() {
        return service;
    }

    public void setService(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "Budget_Request_Info", nillable=true)
    @XmlInverseReference(mappedBy="project")
    public BudgetRequestInfo getBudgetRequestInfo() {
        return budgetRequestInfo;
    }

    public void setBudgetRequestInfo(BudgetRequestInfo budgetRequestInfo) {
        this.budgetRequestInfo = budgetRequestInfo;
    }
    @XmlElement(name = "Material_Request_Assignment", nillable=true)
    @XmlInverseReference(mappedBy="project")
    public List<MaterialRequestAssignment> getMaterialRequestAssignment() {
        return materialRequestAssignment;
    }

    public void setMaterialRequestAssignment(
            List<MaterialRequestAssignment> materialRequestAssignment) {
        this.materialRequestAssignment = materialRequestAssignment;
    }




}
```

Comment: Can you post the source for `Project`?

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan just posted project, it has several dependencies as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-22)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

I have not been able to reproduce the issue you are seeing.  Could you help provide more information so that I can reproduce the problem?  Here is what I have tried:

1. Removed JPA & Hibernate annotations from `Project` class to get it to compile.
2. Created empty `ResponseWrapper` class for `Project` and `Projects` to extend.
3. Created classes for each class referenced by `Project`.
4. When a property is marked with `@XmlInverseReference` added the `project` property on the corresponding type:

   ```
   public class Contract {

       private Project project;

       public Project getProject() {
           return project;
       }

       public void setProject(Project project) {
           this.project = project;
       }

   }
   ```
5. Ran the following demo code:

   ```
   import java.io.File;
   import javax.xml.bind.*;

   public class Demo {

       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
           JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Projects.class);

           Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
           File xml = new File("src/forum19953731/input.xml");
           Projects projects = (Projects) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);
       }

   }
   ```